# Getting specific values and words form a data-dump

Tags: java, android, string, list, substring

I'm working with android and dump a list of all the sensors available to me on a device.

```
[{
        Sensor name = "xyz123", vendor = "vxyz123", version = 1, type = 1, maxRange = 19.123456, resolution = 5.123456E-4, power = 0.4, minDelay = 5000
    }, {
        Sensor name = "yyz123", vendor = "vyyz123", version = 1, type = 1, maxRange = 19.123456, resolution = 5.123456E-4, power = 0.4, minDelay = 5000
    }....
}]
```

The data is display in this fashion for all the sensors, I don't know how many there are and it may vary from device to device.

My question is how do I modify the list so I just show the "Sensor name" and "vendor" key value pairs?

Comment: seems like json, load it into a  json object and then you take what you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my purpose I did:

```
for (Sensor sensor : deviceSensors) {
        listOfSensors.add("Name: " + sensor.getName() + "\nVendor: " + sensor.getVendor() + "\n\n");
    }
```

Turns out I can just call accessors and it will return the appropriate element.